# How to change style to search txt

Tags: css

I am using a wordpress template and I have a problem with search button. I have 2 search widgets on my page. 1 widget is ok. It's 240x25px with search area 190x25px and it's working properly. But the second widget is 960x25px, but search area is 190x25px too. I can change search area in style.css, but if i change to 900px first widget is going crazy. I have text "szukaj tutaj" which means "search here" and if i change width to 900px that test goes under first search widget.

```
/*------------------------------ SEARCH ------------------------------*/
#s {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    color: #818181;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 190px;
}

.searchbtn {
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 25px;
```

Thats the first and second search widget
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` to adjust the `input` based on the container size.

```
.searchform .searchtxt {
    width: 90%;
}
```

Of course, 90% isn't exact. Since the `div.searchform` has two childs, the `input` and the `submit` button, you can't use `width: 100%` for the `input`. If you can use `calc()` based on your [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) needs, I suggest the following code to be more precise:

```
.searchform .searchbtn {
    width: 30px; /* I don't know the searchbtn size, look for it in your CSS. */
}

.searchform .searchtxt {
    width: calc(100% - 50px); /* 30px from the .searchbtn size + 20px for input padding (10px each side). */
}
```

Comment: Hmm i added that to my search widget in style css section (pic: puu.sh/nJXKQ/708b435297.png) but it doenst change anything :/ Have you any other ideas?

Comment: Your styles inside `#s { ... }` are more specific because it's an id selector. So, the class selector that I showed are overriden. Of course, selectors by id normally aren't a good idea. Read more about [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to understand better where to put your styles.

Comment: I still dont get it.. I put that in my css: puu.sh/ofr1x/08c1267182.png but search area is still the same, but everything else is even worse. The search button is way too close.

Comment: Man, you really need to "read more about [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)" as I suggested. Your CSS still has styling by `#id` fighting with styling by `.classes`.